# Подскажите замену технологии Qt для кросплатформенной разработки под Windows и MacOS

Tags: qt, netbeans, кроссплатформенность

Как я понял исходя из текста на официальном сайте Qt - при написании на бесплаьной втке Qt могут возникнуть некоторые проблемы с лицензированием если свой исходный код не расшарить.
Подскажите аналог Qt
Требования: 
1. Чтобы собиралось в не декомпилируемые бинарники.
2. Легкое создание пользовательского интерфейс(не NodeJS и не html)
3.Язык желательно с++ или java.
Соответственно NetBeans декомпилируемый и не подходит.
Целевые платформы Windows и MacOS.
Платформа разработки Windows.

Comment: «*Qt стала платной (или по условиям бесплатной версии надо расшаривать свой исходный код).*» — ЛПП...

Comment: Ну формально она платная. А по условиям бесплатной лицензии надо код опубликовать 
  http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_31501_0.html   Плюс вроде новые официальные дистрибы платные. Ну не официально можно пользоваться наверно. Есть ли замена чтобы в бинарники собирала. Я нашел только NW.js :)

Comment: дык нитка о том, что Qt просто переезжал на новый сайт и ссылки на загрузки в инсталяторах для форточек поломались... некоторые слишком серьёзно на это отреагировали... ничего не изменилось, всё по прежнему есть GPL v2/v3, есть комерческая лицензия и есть LGPLv3... так что линкуйся динамически (вообще говоря) и можешь оставить исходники себе... ну и для особых гиков от юриспруденции можно ещё добавит в бинарник, что используется кьют и ссылку на LGPL...

Comment: java -> javaFx, вроде можно собрать инсталятор, можно юзать обфускаторы.
Еще есть Gtk, для С++ есть биндинг gtkmm, интерфейс можно накидать в glade, но по началу можно испугаться.

Comment: @Василий а нужно прям как Qt или там что то небольшое сделать и разухабистая библиотека не нужна?

Comment: Нужны стандартно поля ввода, таблицы, кнопки, комбобоксы. Будет 10 полей ввода, таблица и много панелек(кнопок или панелек) В Qt это все немного крипово выглядит по сравнению с native, но такое пойдет. Желательно не декомпилируемое а то б на c# winforms или netbeans написал.

Comment: Пока иделя проект на flutter для android и ios. А для винды netbeans или NW.js. Но NW.js не популярна - боюсь наткнуться на невозможность доработок проекта до нужного статуса. Electron (js) декомпилируемый да и не хочу такое:)

Comment: flutter для сайта очень сырой и тормозной не смотря на заверения разрабов что оптимизировали.  flutter для винды в продакшен тоже чет не хочется - захейтят. Хотел вообще сайт не писать а написать на Qt(десктоп) + Flutter(мобайл). Но чет офиц сайт Qt хочет 3000$ в год - а это в 20 раз первышает потенциальную пользу проекта:)

Comment: сайт на flutter безбожно тормозит на средней мобилке 2020 года за 12 тр. на компе core i7 вроде норм, но у клиентов мобилки за 12 тр

Answer (score 1):

Есть хорошая библиотека [Nana](http://nanapro.org/).

- лицензия - boost
- поддержка macOS слабенькая (http://nanapro.org/en-us/forum/index.php?u=/topic/141/ggsupporting-maxosx) - но люди пытаются

Второй вариант - [WxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/)

- лицензия L-GPL, но позволяет линковаться по разному
- поддержка Windows, Unix, macOS.
- использует нативные контролы, что даст красивый интерфейс
- есть даже куча официальных [туториалов](https://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/)

Третий вариант, который уже упоминался - [gtk](https://www.gtk.org/).

- лицензия lgpl, может не подойти.
- поддержка почти всех возможных ОС
- куча туториалов
- это библиотека с си интерфейсом, хоть и имеет плюсовую обертку. Вначале может быть не для слабонервных.

Странный, но интересный вариант - [ImGui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui)

- лицензия - free and permissive
- поддержка многих ос
- странный UI и немного непривычный способ кодирования интерфейса. Но можно как футуристический интерфейс выдать.

и совсем необычный вариант - delphi/C++Builder. Но тут на любителя и ценителя.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ - расширение кругозора. Как-нибудь посмотрю эти технологии. О а на C++Builder 2006  (и иногда С# Winforms) я отпахал 15 лет на работе (базы данных и Devexpress cxGrid xtraGrid):)  Сама среда дохрена весит вроде + она платная кряк нужен + под мак я не собирал под ней. У нас миллион проектов под C++Builder(ERP система)

Comment: на 2006 билдере сложно отработать 15 лет. Или у нас уже 2021?

Comment: Билдер именовался тогда на год вперед. тоесть он вышел в 2005 "C++Builder 2006" wiki:
On Oct 10, 2005, Borland Software Corporation announced the release of Borland C++Builder (previously codenamed "DeXter").[6] Minimum supported operating system was changed to Windows 2000...." Мы как раз начали его использовать в 2005. Щас месяц до 21 года:) Не пересели на 2009 мы изза того что преобразование (AnsiString) в нем перестало работать. Так и забили на новые версии.. Сидим на старом без поддержки Unicode потому что переезд на новый грозит масштабным рефакторингом работы со строками